# Decrypted xml contains invalid characters when encrypt in linux

Tags: encryption, asp.net-core-3.1, pfx, pkcs#7

I have xml, I do the encryption in linux server and decrypt it in windows server.

After decrypted I m getting ��.... some invalid characters before the xml element.

Its not happen when we do encrytion/decryption in windows servers

Can anyone help me on this ? .net core c#

Code used for encryption:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageToBeEncrypted);
EnvelopedCms envelopedCm = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(bytes));
envelopedCm.Encrypt(new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, cert));
base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(envelopedCm.Encode());
```

Code used for decryption:

```
EnvelopedCms envelopedCm = new EnvelopedCms();
envelopedCm.Decode(input);                
envelopedCm.Decrypt(envelopedCm.RecipientInfos[0], new X509Certificate2Collection(privateCert));
str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(envelopedCm.ContentInfo.Content);
```

Comment: During the encryption there is a Base64 encoding. Where is the Base64 decoding during decryption and what is `input`?

Comment: do we need to handle anything for linux server ?

Comment: Dear @Topaco,Thanks for your comments. During decryption input = Convert.FromBase64String(messageEncrypted);And the input is an xml string its bit length, So i m unable to paste it here